# Can we share controll file in an univarsal (iPhone, iPad) Application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I developed a univarsal application,(iPhone, iPad). But later I tried to make them sepret, so i copied my folder in another directory and then linked my iPhone's control file with iPad's XIBs, and delegated them with Outlets, (my controll file remained in the iPhone folder, i just link them in iPad), after it i removed iPhone XIBs from this folder.

Now my project is working properly, BUT **only if I execute the iPhone version first(even from that different directory), and then execute my iPad version, coz it share's the build file of iPhone**.

But when I try to execute it Initially (after deleting prior installed version from simulator), it doesn't work, as it terminate after throwing following exception.

```
2011-04-23 10:56:01.831 Tuscany[1837:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x01683be9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014785c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0163c628 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0163c59a +[NSException raise:format:] + 58
4   Foundation                          0x000d6b12 -[NSURL(NSURL) initFileURLWithPath:] + 90
5   Foundation                          0x000d6aa0 +[NSURL(NSURL) fileURLWithPath:] + 72
6   Tuscany                             0x0003572c -[SplashScreenViewController readyPlayer] + 77
7   Tuscany                             0x00035a62 -[SplashScreenViewController viewDidLoad] + 296
8   UIKit                               0x003e865e -[UIViewController view] + 179
9   UIKit                               0x0035e026 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 51
10  UIKit                               0x0035d511 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 303
11  UIKit                               0x0035d301 -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 50
12  UIKit                               0x0a2ac110 -[UIWindowAccessibility(SafeCategory) _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 56
13  UIKit                               0x0035bfb5 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 39
14  Tuscany                             0x00003205 -[AppDelegate_iPad application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 1472
15  UIKit                               0x0033b1fa -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1163
16  UIKit                               0x0033d55e -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 439
17  UIKit                               0x00347db2 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1533
18  UIKit                               0x00340202 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71
19  UIKit                               0x00345732 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
20  GraphicsServices                    0x01ce3a36 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
21  CoreFoundation                      0x01665064 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
22  CoreFoundation                      0x015c56f7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
23  CoreFoundation                      0x015c2983 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
24  CoreFoundation                      0x015c2240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
25  CoreFoundation                      0x015c2161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
26  UIKit                               0x0033cfa8 -[UIApplication _run] + 636
27  UIKit                               0x0034942e UIApplicationMain + 1160
28  Tuscany                             0x00002b30 main + 102
29  Tuscany                             0x00002ac1 start + 53
)
    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

here to mention i have worked hard with the line i'm establishing connection, and as i told same code run properly when I execute iPhone version first and then the iPad.

so please guied me with this,

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it says.

In the readyPlayer method you are trying to give a nil value to the fileUrlWithPath method.

You need to check why the path is nil.

Comment: Thank you a lot.. i have been stuck up with with it since last three days.. thanks again.. :)